# replaceWith not firing after successful AJAX call

Tags: jquery, replacewith

The first `replaceWith` event that happens right after the `on change` event works fine. For some reason the 2 `replaceWith` in the `success` section of my AJAX call do not fire. I can add `alert("test");` and that works fine. Not sure what I am missing here.

```
$('.addsheet1').on('change', function() {
    $('.sheet1upprog').replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i>'); //works fine
    var id = $('.id').val();
    var formdata = new FormData();
    jQuery.each($('.addsheet1')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        formdata.append('addsheet1', file);
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "addsheet1only.php?id="+id,
        data : formdata,
        type : "post",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            if (data == 'ok') {
                alert("test"); //works fine
                $('.sheet1upprog').replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-check"></i>').delay(1000); //does not work
                $('.sheet1upprog').replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>'); //does not work
            }
        },
        failure: function(){
            $(this).addClass("error");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you add the section of the html that you are trying to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first `replaceWith` call, you have already removed the tag with class `sheet1upprog`, so it is not available subsequent times (in your success callback).

I guess what you are looking for is this -

```
$(".sheet1upprog").html("<new_html_content_here>");
```

Comment: so `replaceWith` functions like `replaceClass`?

Comment: replaceWith replaces the entire tag and all its inner content with the expression you specified.